# flex problems in using it to compile

Tags: lex

I create a simple test for `lex`:

%{

#include 
%}

%%

stop    printf("Stop command received\n");

start   printf("Start command received\n");

%%

name it as `aaa`, but I can't use flex to compile it. Is there something wrong with my procedure? I just use `flex example`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include` without something to include is an error.

If you name it `aaa`, you probably need to do `flex aaa`, not `flex example`.